# How do I determine a rectangle on the basis of the given lengths?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

If I have 4 sides given to me, How do I determine if those 4 sides form a rectangle?
Currently, what I am doing is:

1. Taking 4 sides of sides as an input in an array of size 4;
2. `sort(array,array+4)` sorting the array
3. for(int i=0;i<2;i+=2)
   {
       if(a[i] != a[i+1])
       {
           flag = false;
           break;
       }
   }

But, Here I am just checking if the 4 sides are parallelogram or not. How do I change my algorithm such that it checks if it's a rectangle or not

Comment: You can't uniquely reconstruct a quadrilateral from the sides.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What exactly is a "side" that is given to you--a double value? If that is all you know, you cannot distinguish between a rectangle and a parallelogram, since the lengths of the sides do not determine the figures. You also need information about the angles, or the diagonals, or the coordinates of the vertices, or some such.

Comment: the value is not double. It is int..

Comment: I think you can get it by first checking if there are only four unique points given. Secondly, calculating all pair distance you must get maximum three distinct value. One for each diagonal and two for two sides. Then the sides must fulfill Pythagorean relation.

Comment: If you're given only the lengths, you won't be able to determine whether the shape is a rectangle or not. If you're given the coordinates of the shape vertices, then it should be possible provided that you know which 2 vertices define a particular length. You will have to provide more information.

Comment: I thought like you did when you said you're checking if it's a parallelogram, but you're no even doing that. Just because two sides of a quadrilateral are equal in length doesn't mean it's a parallelogram.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get it by

1. First checking if there are only four unique points given.
2. Secondly, calculating all pair distance you must get maximum three distinct value. One for each diagonal and two for two sides.
3. Then the sides must fulfill Pythagorean relation.

Answer (score 1):

Rectangle (unlike triangle) in not a *rigid* polygone; that's why if you are given four length only, you have *infinitely many* possible figures. E.g. in the simplest `[1, 1, 1, 1]` case we can have either quadrate (which is *rectangle*) or one of numerous rhombs (which are *not*). If we state the problem as

```
  If any rectangle can be constructed with given lengths (lengths can be used in arbitrary order)
```

we can solve it in this way

1. Obtain all four lengths
2. Sort them in ascending order
3. Check `length[0] > 0` (all lengths are positive)
4. Check `length[0] == length[1] && length[2] == length[3]`

In case order should be *preserved* (we can't *rearrange* lengths):

1. Obtain all four lengths
2. Check (in loop) that `length[i] > 0` (all lengths are positive)
3. Check `length[0] == length[2] && length[1] == length[3]`

Answer (score 1):

For a rectangle, you have to check that the opposite sides (no common vertex) are equal length, and also that both diagonals (no common vertex also) are similar.  If you check all the possibilities, you'll find that the common property is that all the possibilities of segments between vertices with no common points have to be same length (pairs of sides and both diagonals)

Another simpler way is to check that all vertices are in a common circle (with center in the rectangle center), which is the point in common of both diagonals, assume you have vertices at P1, P2, P3, and P4: you get the midpoint C1 = (P1 + P3)/2 and C2 = (P2 + P4)/2 (C1 must be equal C2).  If your figure is a rectangle, all four vertices must lie in a circle with center C1 == C2 == C.  Also, all points must be in a circle. So dist(Pi, C) must be the same.  I think this is the most direct way to check if they form a rectangle.

## NOTE

**With only the side lengths you cannot determine that a cuadrilateral is a rectangle**, as a rhomb has all four sides equal, but is not a rectangle (it fails the test of having all vertices in a circle, as both diagonals are not the same size) and the same is true for a rhomboid (it has sides equals two by two, but diagonals are not the same size, and the vertices don't fall in a common circle)

If you have four sides and also the two diagonals, the sides must be equals by alternate pairs and the diagonals must be equal length for them to form a rectangle.